# fs.readFile read only 2 first symbols

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to use sdk fs like that:

```
  var fs = require('sdk/io/fs');

  fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
    if (components.isSuccessCode(error)) {
      var lines = data.toString().split(/[\r\n]+/);
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        listener.process(lines[i]);
      }
    }
    else {
      callback({error: error});
    }
  }
```

but i only get 2 first symbols of file(2 mb). Why i get such a weird behaviour?

Declaration of readFile from sdk:

```
function readFile(path, encoding, callback) {
    if (isFunction(encoding)) {
      callback = encoding
      encoding = null
    }

    let buffer = null;
    try {
      let readStream = new ReadStream(path);
      readStream.on("data", function(data) {
        if (!buffer){
          buffer = data;
        }
        else{
          buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data], 2);
        }
      });

      readStream.on("error", function onError(error) {
        callback(error);
      });

      readStream.on("end", function onEnd() {
        // Note: Need to destroy before invoking a callback
        // so that file descriptor is released.
        readStream.destroy();
        callback(null, buffer);
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      setTimeout(callback, 0, error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Have you checked if the file contains binary data?

Comment: yes, only utf8 content separated by break lines

Comment: Have you tried to use the `sdk/io/file` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use fs.readFile use OS.file: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

Comment: I probably could figure it out if I looked at it, but its strongly strongly recommended to use OS.File. If you really can't use OS.File let me know and i'll look at it.

Comment: I can use OS.File, but it's really interesting for me to know reason of this strange behaviour. If you could figure it out i would be very grateful)

Comment: Ok man Im busy with finishing an addon for the australis competion, which is due in like 10 days so plz remind me after that and ill look at this

Comment: Ah thanks Ill look into this soon and let u know if i can figure it out.